# React Typescript: Exporting types containing enums

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, enums, interface

I have the following files:

CarBrands.ts:

```
export enum CarBrands {
  SAAB = "saab",
  VOLVO = "volvo"
}
```

CarBrand.ts:

```
import {CarBrands} from "./CarBrands";

export type CarBrand = CarBrands.SAAB | CarBrands.VOLVO;
```

Car.ts:

```
import {CarBrand} from "./CarBrand";

export default interface Car {
  brand: CarBrand;
}
```

DefaultCar.ts:

```
import Car from "./Car";

export const DefaultCar: Car = {
  brand: "volvo"
};
```

In the last file where I am exporting "DefaultCar" I get the following error: `TS2322: Type '"volvo"' is not assignable to type 'CarBrands'` even though "brand" should be of type "CarBrand" and not "CarBrands". Why is this?

I have also tried `export type CarBrand = typeof CarBrands.SAAB | typeof  CarBrands.VOLVO;` but this did not work either.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but googling did not help me at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because "volvo" is inferred as `string` and not the `enum`. Here, multiple ways to do it: https://tsplay.dev/PmLbew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a lot more entries in your enum and you *don't* want them in `CarBrand`, why not use the enum directly?

Also, even though the enum is string based, you cannot assign a string to the property without a cast. Instead, use `CarBrands.VOLVO`

```
import {CarBrands} from "./CarBrands";

export default interface Car {
  brand: CarBrands;
}
```

```
import Car from "./Car";

export const DefaultCar: Car = {
  brand: CarBrands.VOLVO
};
```

[Simplified TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwEILiAJgZygbwLABQUUAygIJlJQC8UARJnHAEZ0A0hxAagPIAyvGvQBuAewA2YuoQC+hQgEsQAF2AIAZnADGwWIlycozVBgBce5CawBuWfIJbRITMqgARYJrDjl8BOb8hfCIjKwDEFDQsADpeAR5ZWwJCR2cJYGj0BQQACg8vHz8ASmsgA)

If you would prefer, you could instead just use strings like this:

```
export type CarBrand = 'saab' | 'volvo';
```

And in that case, your property assignment of `'volvo'` would work because it is a matching string.

Comment: I see your point. The enum will have a lot of entries in the end. But I think your solution is the best.